# Display created/modified fields of django_extensions in admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin, django-extensions

I have a class based on `TimeStampedModel` from `django-extentions`:

```
from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel


class MyClass(TimeStampedModel):
    pass
```

By default in the admin interface the `created` and `modified` fields are not displayed in the edition page `my_app/myclass/id`.

I tried this hack to force the display of the `created` and `modified` fields in the edit admin page for `MyClass`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from my_app.models import MyClass


class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = MyClass._meta.get_all_field_names()

admin.site.register(MyClass, MyClassAdmin)
```

But this raised the following exception:

```
Exception Type:     FieldError
Exception Value:    Unknown field(s) (modified, created) specified for MyClass. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class MyClassAdmin.
```

Any idea how can I display the `created` and `modified` fields in the `MyClass` edition admin interface?

**Note 1:** `MyClass` is a model with a lot of fields including `ManyToMany` fields. I can display all the fields except the `created` and `modified` fields from the base class `TimeStampedModel`.

**Note 2:** The admin page in reference is the edition page of a row: `my_app/myclass/id`

Comment: Where you want to view created and modified?

Comment: I would like to display the value in the `MyClass` admin page.

Comment: Why you don't display them in list view with list_dsiplay?

Comment: In fact I simplified the `MyClass` definition. In real, I have a `ManyToMany` field that isn't supported by `list_display`.

Comment: Your question does not describe a problem with a ManyToMany field, so what is your actual question? how could you display a ManyToMany field? or how do you display the Timestamps?

Comment: Of course it's supported. You can add custom functions in list_display, and you can join values from many to many to string. :)

Comment: I have edited the question based on your comments. The problem is on the display of the `created` and `modified` fields. I hope it's clear now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to use the [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) attribute:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from my_app.models import MyClass


class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('created', 'modified', )

admin.site.register(MyClass, MyClassAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Created and Modified are self-managed fields. I think that "hack" the functionality is not good idea. You can display these fields in list display as follow:

For many to many problem:

```
def <funcname>(self, obj):
    return ', '.join([object.<object_field_you_want_to_display> for object in obj.<manyTomanyField>.all()])

<funcname>.short_description = 'Wanted name for column'
```

Then in list_display:

```
list_display = (...., '<funcname>')
```

And then you want to display all fields you want (created and modified too)

```
list_display(...all fields you want ..., '<funcname>', 'created', 'modified')
```

But if you still think that it's good idea you should add these fields in your template (/includes/fieldset.html). But you should first write context processor and/or template tag to get the write value ... and so on...

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but I would like to modify the display in the edit page of the admin interface, ie. `my_app/myclass/id`. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I modidfied my answer. I think it's not a good idea because created and modified are self-managed. If you want to display values (not to change) you can display it in template (.../includes/fieldset.html). You should first write context processor :)

Comment: If my understanding is good,`list_display` modify the display when we display the list of all the `MyClass` values not in the edition page of one `MyClass` instance.

Comment: list_display is not in your edition page, yes. So if you want to have created and modified in edition page, i tell you ... in your template you can display it. In your templates you can display all you want.